# How to parse R123[i] pattern inside string in variable using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have expression like this

```
R4013[i] == 3 and R4014[i] == 2 AND R40[i] == 1 and R403[i+1] == 5 and R404[i+1] == 2 AND R405[i+1] == 1 R231[2]
```

I want to grap all the variable here with regex so I get variable `R4013[i]`,`R4014[i]`,`R40[i]` and so on.

I have already have regex pattern like this but not work

`[RMB].+\[.+\]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below,

```
@"[RMB][^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dC0nM5/2)

- `[RMB]` Picks up a single character from the given list.
- `[^\[]*` negated character class which matches any character but not `[` symbol, zero or more times.
- `\[` Matches a literal `[` symbol.
- `[^\]]*` Matches any character but not of `]`, zero or more times.
- `\]` Matches the literal `]` symbol.

**Code:**

```
String input = @"R4013[i] == 3 and R4014[i] == 2 AND R40[i] == 1 and R403[i+1] == 5 and R404[i+1] == 2 AND R405[i+1] == 1 R231[2]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[RMB][^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/eGFB4T)

Answer (score 0):

```
R\d+\[[^\]]*\]
```

This simple regex should do it, see demo:

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/3

Or you can simply modify your own regex to make it `non greedy`. Your regex uses `.+` which is greedy and so it was capturing all data up to last `[]` instead of each variable. `.+` is greedy and will not stop at the first instance of `[` which you want. So use `.+?` instead

```
[RMB].+?\[.+?\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/4

Your regex `[RMB].+\[.+\]` will capture up to last `[]` as you have `.+` after `[RMB]`. [See here](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/5)

```
string strRegex = @"[RMB].+?\[.+?\]";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"R4013[i] == 3 and R4014[i] == 2 AND R40[i] == 1 and R403[i+1] == 5 and R404[i+1] == 2 AND R405[i+1] == 1 R231[2]";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but I don't know why this regex `[RMB].+?\[.+?\]` not work in http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: @mrhands do you mind sharing why you accepted the other answer?

Comment: @vks It amazes me how answers that state "You can try the below" ... without an explanation of the problem get upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @hwnd OP accepted mine and said its wroking.Next moment he accepts the other answer!!!!!!!!!!!!